# Slidebar which can be adjusted manually

Tags: javascript

I did a Slidebar (0-99) which is working well.
I want to add 2 buttons to manually change it (first button -1 ; second button +1).
It was working well with my "-1" code for the first button, but the second one isnt working and I dont understand why. (It add 1 but for example if my slidebar is at 50, when i click its not going to 51 but 501).

Here is my code :

```html
<div>
   <button id="moins1" onclick="moins1()">MOINS 1</button>
   <span class="unselectable rangeValue1" id="rangeValue1">RR</span>
   <Input class="range" type="range" name="BarreRR" value="0" min="0" max="99" onChange="rangeSlide1(this.value)" onmousemove="rangeSlide1(this.value)"></Input>
   <button id="plus1" onclick="plus1()">PLUS 1</button>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function rangeSlide1(value) {
    document.getElementById('rangeValue1').innerHTML = value;
   }
   
   function moins1(){
    var Yop = document.getElementById('rangeValue1').textContent;
    Yop -=1;
    document.getElementById('rangeValue1').innerHTML = Yop;
    console.log(Yop);
   }
   function plus1(){
    var Yop = document.getElementById('rangeValue1').textContent;
    Yop +=1;
    document.getElementById('rangeValue1').innerHTML = Yop;
    console.log(Yop);
   }
</script>
```

Thanks for help, Zartex.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that textContent returns string and using + operator will try to concatenate the values. So you can parse it. But I would recommend directly connecting your range with displayed value and only alter the range using the buttons or change them together for example:

```js
   function rangeSlide1(value) {
        document.getElementById('rangeValue1').innerHTML = value;
      }
    
      function moins1() {
        let range = document.querySelector('.range')
        if (range.value != 0) {
          let newValue = range.value - 1
          document.getElementById('rangeValue1').innerHTML = newValue
          range.value = newValue
        }
      }
    
      function plus1() {
        let range = document.querySelector('.range')
        if (range.value < 99) {
          let newValue = Number(range.value) + 1
          document.getElementById('rangeValue1').innerHTML = newValue
          range.value = newValue
       }
      }
```

```html
    <div>
      <button id="moins1" onclick="moins1()">MOINS 1</button>
      <span class="unselectable rangeValue1" id="rangeValue1">RR</span>
      <Input class="range" type="range" name="BarreRR" value="0" min="0" max="99" onChange="rangeSlide1(this.value)" onmousemove="rangeSlide1(this.value)"></Input>
      <button id="plus1" onclick="plus1()">PLUS 1</button>
    </div>
```

Considering your range is limited from 0 to 100 I added condition not to go under 0

Comment: It'd likely be a good call to enforce the upper boundary on the `plus1` as well. For completeness — and since this is a pretty infamous corner of JavaScript — the [MDN page on _type coercion_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Type_coercion) might be a good read.

Comment: Good call about the upper range.

Comment: Also, if you're still wondering _"Why does the minus operator work?"_, that's because there isn't a minus operation on strings (or anything other than a number) in JavaScript. As a result, the string is coerced into a number; exactly the opposite of what happened with the plus operator. This is the case even when the string isn't numeric. For example, `"hello" - 1` evaluates to `NaN`.

Comment: Hey ! Thanks a lot, you're code worked perfectly ! Im sorry i had the corona so I was not answering. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

it will help you,
Yop value always in "50" + 1 it will return by concat 501
so parseInt your string and add/minus by 1

```
function moins1(){
     var Yop = document.getElementById('rangeValue1').textContent;
     Yop = parseInt(Yop)-1;
     document.getElementById('rangeValue1').innerHTML = Yop;
    console.log(Yop);
 }
function plus1(){
       var Yop = document.getElementById('rangeValue1').textContent;
        Yop = parseInt(Yop)+1;
        document.getElementById('rangeValue1').innerHTML = Yop;
        console.log(Yop);
  }
```